# IPhone app with WebView - moving the web files into a sub-folder

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview

I've inherited an iphone app which is basically a webview with all the web files (html/js/css) included as resources. I want to move the files from the root of the project (where they are now), to a sub-folder (www).

So, I've created the folder and moved all my files into it. In XCode, I removed them all from the root (they were all red and flagged as missing). I then added the new folder to the project - all looks good.

I then checked inside `Build Phases` in the project settings, and the same files were there - all my .js files in the www folder are showing as "Compile Sources" (as they were before from the root), and all the images etc are all showing as "Copy bundle resources" as they were before.

So when I run the app on the emulator (after resetting it), it appears to all work OK. If I change the HTML, I see the updates too. BUT, if I change the js files in any way (adding alerts all over the place, removing all the content, anything!), then no matter what I do I don't see the changes - it's like it's serving up my old .js files from somewhere, even when I reset the emulator again.

Can anyone advise what to do? My web view code is below in case it makes any difference:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [imageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [self setWebView:webView];
    [webView setDelegate:self];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    imageView.hidden = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution (though not very elegant) could be to wrap your scripts with a timestamp to avoid caching. Assuming your scripts are in the head tag:

```
<script>
    document.write('<script src="yourScript.js?' + new Date().getTime() + '><\/script>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seem to have this working.

When you add the folder/files to the project, if you choose `Create folder references for any added folders` - this doesn't add the js files as sources, and the other files as resources, but instead adds the entire folder as a resource (so the folder structure is maintained).

Then, you just need to tell your webview about the new location for the index.html (or whatever)

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"www]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

And now it's working :)